# How to import a radio station list from Rhythmbox to Banshee?

Tags: 10.04, banshee

I want to try Banshee on Lucid and have to import all my radio station lists, so I wonder how to do this automatically instead of importing each one by hand.

I have several radio stations in Rhythmbox and the process would be very tiresome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether this is the best way, but I created a play-list of Armenian radio stations, Armenian.m3u

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1,Beirut, Lebanon - Bashdee
http://yp.shoutcast.com/sbin/tunein-station.pls?id=546514
#EXTINF:-1,Istanbul, Turkey - Nor Radyo
http://www.norradyo.com:8000/
#EXTINF:-1,Moscow, Russia - Armenia.ru
http://radio.armenia.ru/pls/listen.pls
#EXTINF:-1,International - Armenian Bible Study Radio
http://sc7.mystreamserver.com:8036
#EXTINF:-1,International - Armenian Pulse Radio
http://yp.shoutcast.com/sbin/tunein-station.pls?id=416989
#EXTINF:-1,International - Arm Radio
http://www.realradios.com/x/stream/50536
#EXTINF:-1,Yerevan, Armenia - Public Radio of Armenia
http://www.armradio.am/eng/live/listens.pls
#EXTINF:-1,Yerevan, Armenia - Public Radio of Armenia - Shoutcast
http://yp.shoutcast.com/sbin/tunein-station.pls?id=898669
#EXTINF:-1,Yerevan, Yerevan, Armenia - AR Radio Intercontinental
http://www.realradios.com/x/stream/50541
#EXTINF:-1,Yerevan, Yerevan, Armenia - Yerevan Nights Radio
http://www.realradios.com/x/stream/46211
#EXTINF:-1,Boston, MA - Hairenik Radio
http://www.live365.com/play/acaa
#EXTINF:-1,International - AIM Radio
http://www.live365.com/play/aimmedia
```

So I can maintain this list separately and then import it into Banshee after upgrades.
I wish, however, for Banshee to be more user-friendly with add/remove/update/export/import of on-line radio stations, as this way seems to be not very intuitive (at least to me).

Comment: I think we need to give answer to move playlists from rhythmbox to banshee. Any ideas?

Comment: From what I understood, internally Banshee stores radio stations as "tracks". It's a matter of writing a script that would read it from Rhythmbox configuration file and write it correctly into Banshee database. I don't know how to do that and nobody seems to care to do it. It is a much anticipated feature, but I wonder if Banshee developers pay any attention.

Comment: Agreed. Alternatively a longer list of shoutcast/icecast or which ever community radio links that work and are searchable would be useful. I used to be able to do this but recently this proved really hard to manage

Answer (score 1):

Install one of these plugins:

**banshee-extension-liveradio** - LiveRadio extension for Banshee

**banshee-extension-radiostationfetcher** - radio station fetcher extension for Banshee

Comment: -1: This is a great way to add new radio stations to Banshee, but the question is about importing a set of radio stations from Rhythmbox.

Answer (score 1):

The default stations are:

80s

```
http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/ogg/live.pls?service=a8bb

http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/ogg/live.pls?service=a8
```

Classic Rock

```
http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/ogg/live.pls?service=vcbb
```

90s

```
http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/ogg/live.pls?service=a9bb
```

POP

```
http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/ogg/live.pls?service=vrbb
```

dabbl

```
http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/ogg/live.pls?service=albb
```

HBR1 – Dream Factory

```
http://ubuntu.hbr1.com:19800/ambient.ogg
```

Trance

```
http://ubuntu.hbr1.com:19800/trance.ogg
```

You can take any of these URLs and add them to Banshee. To do this start Banshee up and then follow the images below to add the stations you prefer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This seems to be about moving radio sations as a list from rhythmbox to banshee....any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The question is exporting a radio list not adding a station hand by hand.

So far there is no way to do this in any player banshee or rhythmbox

Answer (score 1):

You can use xmlstarlet to pull the essential data out of your XML file.  See here for details:

http://steffen67.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-export-rhythmbox-radio-stations.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I just edited it to include the main idea.  (Thanks for the link.  I was worried that reposting other info would be duplicating web data unnecessarily.)