# Importing RadioTray radio stations into Banshee

Tags: banshee, internet-radio

I read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/112536/46531) and would like to know whether it was possible in a similar way for `Banshee` also? Can I import radio stations I listen to in `RadioTray` to `Banshee` without adding them by hand (which would take a long time)?

I've read the following Ask Ubuntu Q&As:

1. [Is it possible to import/export radio station as a list into/from Banshee](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42840/is-it-possible-to-import-export-radio-station-as-a-list-into-from-banshee)
2. [How to import a radio station list from Rhythmbox to Banshee?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28203/how-to-import-a-radio-station-list-from-rhythmbox-to-banshee)

These touch my question - but are slightly different. And without usable answers, at least in my case.